Figure out which of your friends reveals confidential information to the media!
Exposition
You send secret information to 100 of your friends, and the next day you discover that the information has been published! Who could have revealed it?
To determine that, you number your friends 0...99 and encode the number in the message by altering spaces in it. You can replace each space " " by one or two spaces " " or " ". Your unscrupulous friend will forward the message exactly as it is to the public media, and you will determine who it is by analyzing the spaces.
(I heard that something like this happened in real life, but couldn't find the details; is it an urban legend?)
Input
Your code must receive a text message (you can assume it's ASCII) and a number in the range 0...99. The message will not contain two adjacent spaces; it will not have space as a first or last character. It will contain at least 7 spaces.
The most obvious algorithm is to use a binary encoding of the input number. However, if you want to use another algorithm (e.g. unary), you can require the input message to contain any minimal number of spaces, up to 101.
Output
The output must be the same as input, with some spaces replaced by double spaces. The output must be different for different input numbers - it should be possible to discover the input number from the output message.
Twist
Your code should be a valid input to itself! That is, it can't contain two spaces one after another, and it should be able to output at least 100 different versions of itself when given to itself as input. And any output version of the code (with some of the spaces doubled) should do exactly the same as the original version.
Examples

Input: message = "Here is one example with 7 spaces. Seven!", number = 22
Possible output: "Here  is one  example  with 7 spaces. Seven!"

Input: message = "a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a", number = 33
Possible output: "a  a  a  a  a  a  a  a  a  a  a  a  a  a  a  a  a  a  a  a  a  a  a  a  a  a  a  a  a  a  a  a  a  a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a"

Input: "1 2 3 4 5 6 7"
Output: Undefined behavior - the input is invalid, contains too few spaces

Code: lambda s, x: ''.join(map(lambda a: a[0]+a[1],zip(s.split(),map(lambda n: (n+1)*' ',chain(map(int,list(bin(x)[2:])),repeat(0))))))[:-1]
Input: message = code, number = 42
Possible output: lambda  s, x:  ''.join(map(lambda a:  a[0]+a[1],zip(s.split(),map(lambda n: (n+1)*' ',chain(map(int,list(bin(x)[2:])),repeat(0))))))[:-1]

In the last example, I feed the code to itself. I had to add extra spaces to the code so it would satisfy the twist condition. Note: the last space in the code is essential to its correct execution - it should never be doubled! I had to make sure the code contains 7 spaces before it to ensure it wouldn't happen.

I wonder if it's possible to solve this challenge using the whitespace language. Are there any other languages for which it's hard but possible?

The output must be the same as input, with some spaces replaced by double spaces. Can one of the output versions have zero doubled spaces? That seems to be implied since you mention binary encoding of the input number, but can you clarify?

About the real-life story: probably not the one you mean, but the challenge reminded me of this

Yes, unchanged input message for one of the input numbers is OK.

You may be thinking of the Wagatha Christie (wikipedia) case.   They outed the leak using privacy settings rather than encoded messages.

It is also common to watermark private beta versions of video games to discourage players from leaking footage.

Wikipedia (Canary Trap) lists several of these, including one by Tesla. One leaker of Apple material shut down after Apple caught his source using such methods.

Python, 63 bytes
lambda s,n:"".join(c*-~(c<"!" and [n&1,n:=n//2][0]) for c in s)

Attempt This Online!
Neatly spaced keywords to ensure it contains 7 spaces.

05AB1E, 24 21 bytes
.γ ð Q } I b € 0ÅÏº}J

Try it online or verify all test cases.
Explanation:
.γ         # Adjacent group-by on the first (implicit) input-string:
  ðQ       #  Check if the current character is a space
 }I        # After the group-by: push the second input-integer
   b       # Convert it to a binary-string
    €0     # Put a 0 before each bit (and convert it to a binary-list)
      ÅÏ   # Apply on the truthy (==1) positions in the grouped list:
        º  #  Horizontal mirror, to double the space
       }J  # After the truthy-apply: join it back together to a string
           # (which is output implicitly as result)

The no-op spaces to comply to the challenge rules can be added anywhere in the code, except between the .γ and ÅÏ, since those are single 2-byte builtins.

JavaScript (Node.js), 48 bytes
x => n => x . replace (/ /g,c=>2*(n/=2)&1?c+c:c)

Try it online!
-2 B Arnauld
The 8th space would never get doubled so it work correctly

48 bytes

Python, 93 92 91 bytes
lambda s, n : ''.join( [ c +c*((1<<s[:i].count(' ')&n>0)&(c==' '))for i,c in enumerate(s)])

Try it online!
There are exactly 7 spaces before the .count(' ') so it should not be affected for integer inputs <= 128 when feeding itself as the source string
Ungolfed
def ungolfed(input_string, secret_int_to_encode):
    return ''.join(
        [
            character # Always return the base character
            + # Optionally adding the same character multiplied by a value of 0 or 1 based on the challenge conditions
            character * (
                    (
                        1 << input_string[:string_index].count(' ') # The number 1 bitshifted by the number of spaces in the string so far.
                                                                    # This acts as a bitmask against secret_int_to_encode
                        &
                        secret_int_to_encode # Bitwise AND here will return non-zero if the bit representation of the integer has a 1 at this index
                        > 0 # Comparing against 0 to normalize the value as 0 or 1, as opposed to whatever bit of secret_to_encode we might be at
                    ) # This value is 1 if the bitwise representation of the integer to encode has a 1 at this space-based index
                    &
                    (character==' ') # Bitwise AND with 1 if the current character is a whitespace.
                                     # This will null the second character when we are iterating on a char not equal to ' '
                ) for string_index , character in enumerate(input_string)
        ]
    )```


Welcome to Code Golf, and nice first answer! You can omit the space before the for.

@emanresuA Thanks for the tip!

Whitespace, 1004 bytes
 a b c  d                        
 

          

    
 
  
    
      
             
             
        
         
                
       
 
    

     
          

     
    
        
            
            
                
                 
                
                    
                
            
                
            
                
             
                
                
                
             
    
        
    
                      

      
 
             
             
        
            
 
             
        
             

            
    
        
       
 
      

        




         

           
 
                
        
                
 


 
            

        
            
                
             
         
    
  
         
    

                

 
            

        
    

          
 
 
                
     

                 
     
             
                
        
                    
        
                
        
                  
 


    

            
     
             
         
 
             
    

                
     
             
          
     
 
             
    

             
     
             
                     
 
             
    

        
     
             
                 
 
             
    

        
     
             
                 
 
             
    

         
    
             
          
    
 
             
    

            
    
             
                    
 
             
    

            
    
             
                
 
             
    

          
    
             
                
 
             
    

       
    
             
        
 
             
    


Try it online!
This took a minute.
This uses a loophole in the language implementation to allow a trivial solution to the challenge twist, where all but the 3 white space characters are ignored by the interpreter. This means the top instruction (push 10922 onto the stack) is enough to satisfy the twist, since there are the characters a, b, c, and d inserted in remove any consecutive spaces from the source code. I did come up with a non-trivial solution, which would be much more intensive to implement. The call subroutine operation is LF SPC TAB, while the mark label is LF SPC SPC. That means you could make the top instruction of the program 'call subroutine 10922', which might be transformed into either 'mark label 10922', or transform the label itself (10922 in binary is 10101010101010). If there were all 128 possible transformations of that label at the bottom, immediately followed by the return from subroutine operation, it would effectively be a no-op regardless of the transformation.
Explanation
Unfortunately TIO only has version 0.2, so this program cannot use the copy or slide operators. That means it can only use 2 local variables at a time. I did implement a few subroutines to allow the use of heap address 1 and 2 as pseudo registers, which helped.

I don't want to bother making the edit, but there are a few bytes that could be saved because I left in the part of the program that prints the input number in binary, which was used extensively during development if you can imagine. Turns out this was somewhat difficult since Whitespace does not include any bitwise operations.

Nice answer! Smart of pushing the 10922 for this challenge. And manual binary calculations are indeed cumbersome. Btw, I'm not sure about the version, but TIO does have the copy and slide builtins available. I've used copy in this answer and this answer of mine for example. Here is also a TIO that uses both copy and slide without any issues.

Charcoal, 33 bytes
Ｎθ¿ ¿ ¿ ¿ ¿ ⭆η⎇›ι ι… ⊕﹪÷θＸ²№…ηκ ²

Try it online! Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:
Ｎθ

Input n.
¿ ¿ ¿ ¿ ¿ 

Filler commands that do nothing but are required for the source layout. (They're actually if statements, but strings of one or two spaces are both truthy anyway.)
⭆η⎇›ι ι… ⊕﹪÷θＸ²№…ηκ ²

Map over the message, replacing characters that are not greater than one or two spaces (this always covers the rest of printable ASCII) with one or two spaces truncated or cyclically extended to one or two spaces according to the next least significant bit of the input number. The bit index is found by counting spaces so far so this has to be the eighth space for that to work correctly (adding a two byte filler is golfier than any other way of working around it).

Perl 5 -pl, 44 bytes
$a = sprintf "%b", <>; s/$"\K/$"x chop $a/ge

Try it online!
Takes the message on the first input line, the number on the second.
Encodes the friend number in binary in the first 7 spaces, least significant bit first, with one space representing 0 and two spaces representing 1.

Haskell, 73 bytes
f(' ':y)n=(replicate(mod n 2+1)' ')++f y(div n 2);f(x:y)n=x:f y n;f s 0=s

Try it online!

MATL, 20 bytes
t f y 5W=f iB ) hS )

Try it online!
Spaces have no effect on the above code, and can be placed anywhere.
Explanation
t    % Implicit input: string. Duplicate
f    % Find: gives [1 2 ... L], where L is the string length
y    % Push another copy of the string
5    % Push 5
W    % Exponential with base 2: gives 32
=    % Compare, element-wise. Gives true for spaces, false otherwise
f    % Find: gives indices of spaces
i    % Input: number
B    % Binary expansion. Gives true/false for the bits
)    % Use as logical index. Gives indices of spaces selected by the binary expansion
h    % Concatenate horizontally. Attaches those indices to the original [1 2 ... L]
S    % Sort
)    % Use as indices into the stting. Implicit display


APL(Dyalog Unicode), 35 bytes SBCS
Assumes ⎕io←0.
{⍺ ⌿⍨ 1 + ((+\ × ⊢) ' '=⍺)∊⍸⍵⊤⍨8⍴2}

Try it on APLgolf!
{⍺ ⌿⍨ 1 + ((+\ × ⊢) ' '=⍺)∊⍸⍵⊤⍨8⍴2}
 ⍺ ⌿⍨                               ⍝ input string replicated with
      1 +                           ⍝ one more of
          ((+\ × ⊢) ' '=⍺)∊⍸⍵⊤⍨8⍴2  ⍝ mask for spaces that need to be doubled
           (+\ × ⊢) ' '=⍺           ⍝ i if it's the i-th space (1-indexed), 0 for non-spaces
                                    ⍝   'x xxx xxxx x' → 0 1 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 3 0
                          ∊         ⍝ is in
                           ⍸⍵⊤⍨8⍴2  ⍝ which bits are 1 in 8-bit representation of ⍵
                                    ⍝   We take 8-bit representation so the highest possible set bit becomes 1.


The corresponding decoding function is {2⊥¯1++/↑7↑⊆⍨' '=⍵}.
